# Tomcat production server shutdown unexpectedly in logs i found WARNING: Going to buffer response body of large or unknown size

Tags: java, spring, webserver, tomcat7, application-server

The Tomcat production server shut down unexpectedly.
In the logs I found:

```
WARNING: Going to buffer response body of large or unknown size.
Using get Response Body AsStream instead is recommended.
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please add more context.

Comment: This Q&A explains how to fix the warning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745022/whats-the-best-way-to-suppress-a-runtime-console-warning-in-java.  However, I doubt that the warning is connected to your server shutdown ... unless you are trying to generate a monstrously large response.